# How to forward an user to a certain page but not right after they choose an option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding. Currently I'm working on templates for an online software. The user will be able to choose an option with a radio button. But the user shouldn't be redirected to the certain page linked to the radio button before the continue button gets clicked.

I can't include the entire code section, because it's for a company.

Info: The colors are just examples, because I can't use the original definitions for document names and classes/id's.

```
<!-- begin radio buttons-->
<div class="panel-default" id="panel-color">

    <div class="panel-body"><strong>color</strong></div>
        <div class="radio-buttons-color">
            <ul class="radio-buttons-left">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-yellow">
                        <label for="radio2">yellow</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-blue"> 
                        <label for="radio2">blue</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-green"> 
                        <label for="radio2">green</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="radio-buttons-right">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-red">
                        <label for="radio2">red</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-purple"> 
                        <label for="radio2">purple</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-orange"> 
                        <label for="radio2">orange</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end radio buttons -->
```

When the radio button with the label "yellow" is selected for example, the user should be redirected to the html document, which contains the yellow colored pictures. But the user should see this page after he/she clicks the continue button.

Comment: Your `<label>` elements will all affect the same `<input>` element, with `id="radio2"` (assuming it exists). Assuming you want them to target the adjacent `<input>` you need to amend the `for` attribute, in each case, to be the same as the `id` of the relevant `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above using JavaScript. Record the onclick event on the List items you have created to capture the colour on which click has happened. Create a button and redirect the url to that colour url.

```
<div class="panel-default" id="panel-color">
    <div class="panel-body"><strong>color</strong></div>
        <div class="radio-buttons-color">
            <ul class="radio-buttons-left" onclick="clicked(event)">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-yellow" >
                        <label for="radio2">yellow</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-blue"> 
                        <label for="radio2">blue</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-green"> 
                        <label for="radio2">green</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="radio-buttons-right" onclick="clicked(event)">
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-red">
                        <label for="radio2">red</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-purple"> 
                        <label for="radio2">purple</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-orange"> 
                        <label for="radio2">orange</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<a href="" onclick="redirect()"><button>
Continue
</button></a>

    <script>
    var url = ""
function clicked(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
  url = e.target.id;
}

function redirect() {
console.log(url)
window.location.href = url;
}
</script>
```

Refer to https://jsfiddle.net/2kmjudLw/1/ for live demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the radio button id to the next page by passing the query parameter and you can handle the page color in the next page by getting the value from the queryparameter.

```
<button onclick="redirectPage()">Click me</button>

<script>
function redirectPage() {


var checkedRadioBox=document.querySelector('input[name=radio]:checked');



if(checkedRadioBox!=undefined){
    location.href= "https://www.google.com?q="+checkedRadioBox.id;

}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for selecting color. Here we assume that the pages name are same as color name.

```
$("input[name='radio']").on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var color = id.split("-");
    window.location = color[1];//Add page extension here e.g. .php, .html
})
```

Code for getting back to the page

```
    <a id="continue" href="">continue</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#continue').attr('href', document.referrer);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very dependent on your framework, but basically it can be implemented with:

```
let radios = document.querySelector('[name=radio]'); //get all radio inputs

[].forEach.call(radios, (radio)=>{
    radio.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
       let url = e.target.value; // you need to assign redirect url to value attribute for example (<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-yellow" value="http://stackoverflow.com">)
       let confirm = confirm('confirm redirect?'); //built in javascript confirmation modal, returns true if user click OK
       confirm && window.location.href = url; //redirect if ok               
    });  //bind event callback on click to radio button
}); //iterate over radio buttons and set callback function to it
```